# How are neighbouring sequences defined? (Metric spaces)

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, definition

What does it mean for sequences to be neighbours in a metric space?

My attempt is:

In a metric space $(X,d)$, $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ are neighbouring sequences iff $$\forall_{\epsilon>0}\exists_N n\geq N \implies d(x_n,y_n)<\epsilon$$ where $n, N \in \mathbb{N}, \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: This says that the distance between $x_n$ and $y_n$ goes to $0$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$.

Comment: Yes, is that correct or incorrect?

Comment: @ahorn: What do you mean by "correct or incorrect"? It's your definition; you can make the word mean anything you need it to mean.

Comment: Can you give any context where someone uses the term  "neighbouring sequenes"?

Comment: However, the definition you have written now contains $N$ as a free variable. I don't think you want your notion of "neighbors" to depend on a particular value of $N$, such that we'd need to talk about "they're neighbors for $N=42$ but not for $N=5$", do you?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Theorem: Let $f:X\to Y$ be a function and $(X,d_X)$ and $(Y,d_Y)$ be metric spaces. Then $f$ is uniformly continuous if, and only if, whenever $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ are neighbours in $(X,d_X)$, it follows that $(f(x_n))$ and $(f(y_n))$ are neighbours in $(Y,d_Y)$.

Comment: @ahorn: And where did you find that? One would think that place would supply its own definition for "neighbours", rather than expect you to invent one.

Comment: @HenningMakholm in my Metric Spaces university course. I'll go have a look at my course notes. I thought it was a general concept - that's why I decided to ask the question here.

Comment: @HenningMakholm My first thought was $\forall_{\epsilon>0} \forall_{n \in \mathbb{N}} d_X(x_n, y_n)< \epsilon$, but then I saw that a line in the proof required one to choose $N\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $n\geq N \Rightarrow d_X(x_n, y_n)<\delta$. Using my original definition, that line would have been superfluous because it would be true for any $N$

Comment: I suspect that it means that $$\forall\epsilon>0\,\exists m\in\Bbb N\,\forall n\ge m\,d(x_n,y_n)<\epsilon\;.$$ This is equivalent to saying that the sequence $\langle d(x_n,y_n):n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $0$ in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I have changed my definition in response to your comment above about N being a free variable.

Comment: @ahorn: Now $n$ is a free variable, though. You need quantifiers for _both_ $n$ and $N$.